# python) I want to extract only values above 0.9 from the correlation table

Tags: python, filtering, correlation

My correlation table consists of 1446 x 1447.

[image]

Of these, I only want to see numbers greater than 0.9. (Includes 0.9)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Do you mean you need to find where the values are greater than 0.9 (index of each) or visualize them?

Comment: visualization is not required.

However, I want to collect values greater than 0.9 and save them to a file. (For example : csv file)

Comment: Please, post a piece of code, not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where` with condition to find the indexes or actual values satisfied the condition.

```
import numpy as np
table = np.random.rand(1446, 1447)
# get all indexes of elem having value >= 0.9
filtered_idx = np.where(table >= 0.9)
# get all elem values >= 0.9
filtered_values = table[filtered_idx]
assert all(filtered_values >= 0.9)
```